# LaTeX math textbook conversion to ebook/Kindle

Tags: math-mode, ebook, kindle

I'm looking to buy a very math-heavy textbook (LeSage's [Spatial Econometrics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/142006424X)). The Kindle version is about $20 cheaper. Normally, I would be happy with the Kindle version, but I'm nervous about how the formulae will show up in e-type. I know that the text of the book is written in LaTeX, but I don't know about math conversion to e-type Alas, the Kindle preview is not available.

What is the mechanism that Amazon (or other ebook dealers) use to convert LaTeX formulae to electronic type?

Does anyone know of a good Kindle preview for a LaTeX math document?

Comment: As @Przemysław pointed out, this is a `[Print Replica]`, which I assume just means it's the PDF. So math will be fine, but won't actually make the Kindle edition useful.

Comment: Just a comment on "What is the mechanism that Amazon (or other ebook dealers) use to convert LaTeX formulae to electronic type?" I would bet that the use XML as intermediate format.

Comment: Does the licence permit this??

Comment: @MarcvanDongen, who do you think is violating the license?

Comment: What makes you believe I think somebody is violating the licence?

Comment: I can't tell where licensing enters into the discussion (as I assume Amazon is selling products it has negotiated with the publisher), so I was curious as to what your question could mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following:

Print Replica:
This Kindle book **looks just like the printed book**
Available only on Kindle Fire Tablets, iPad, Android Tablets, PC and Mac

suggests that it is PDF not AZW or MOBI.

And a good preview of math documents... Not on any 6" display. Well, I use it sometimes, but it really painfull.

Comment: Ah, I now see what the `[Print Replica]` means. It would seem more useful to sell the .pdf file directly.